# Why this code don't show all values in the database?

Tags: java, sql, database, select

Why this code doesn't show all values in the database ?

```
public Article searchAllArticles(){

    try {

        DbCnx cnx = new DbCnx();
        conn = cnx.connection_a_postgresql();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM my_caisse.articles";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet resultat = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while (resultat.next()) {
            Article article =new Article();
            article.setId_article(resultat.getLong("id_article"));
            article.setDesi_article(resultat.getString("desi_article"));
            article.setPrix_unitaire(resultat.getDouble("prix_unitaire"));
            article.setStock_en_cours(resultat.getInt("stock_en_cours"));
            article.setImg_article(resultat.getString("image_article"));
            afficherArticles(article); //show all the values using System.out.println
            return article;
            //i have 5 lines in the table "my_caisse.articles" and i only have one result (only the first line)
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Because you are calling `return` inside the `while` loop.  In most programming languages that I know of, this would stop reading the results after the first one.

Comment: Because that's what the `return` statement does: it returns a value. If you return a value nothing else can happen inside that method. If you want to return *multiple* results you'll need to return a collection.

Comment: Yet Another Example of why proper code formatting is important.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Which languages do you know of that *don't* work like that?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist . . . When defining an iterator in some object-orient languages, you can return a value and then continue execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you exit the loop with `return article` when the first article is found.

Answer (score 0):

`return article;` inside while loop is the problem. Move it to the last statement of the method where you `return null;` Otherwise, this will cause the execution to return to the calling method during the first iteration of `while` loop itself. See the code below

```
 Article article = null;
  while (resultat.next()) {
        article =new Article();
        article.setId_article(resultat.getLong("id_article"));
        article.setDesi_article(resultat.getString("desi_article"));
        article.setPrix_unitaire(resultat.getDouble("prix_unitaire"));
        article.setStock_en_cours(resultat.getInt("stock_en_cours"));
        article.setImg_article(resultat.getString("image_article"));
        afficherArticles(article); //show all the values using System.out.println
       // return article; remove this line (commented)
        //i have 5 lines in the table "my_caisse.articles" and i only have one result (only the first line)
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return article;
```

I think you also need to add the new instances of `Article` to a `list`. but, you just left them in air. You need to change the return type of the method to `List<Article>` as well

Comment: Your code won't work because `article` isn't visible outside the loop.

Comment: You are welcome! Please close the question by accepting any one of the answers which helped you much :) Click on the tick symbol on the left side of the answer! This helps the passers to know the answer which solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Because you are returning inside the while loop. And your code expects single object (Article) to return. You should create a list, populate the data and return it. Also change the return type to List of Objects (List of Article).